# Vegas pro will not show video for avi with mp4v fourcc codec?

Tags: codec, vegas-pro

I have a few avi videos that are encoded with the mp4v fourcc codec. I have Sony Vegas Pro 8 and it will not open the video part. It will bring the files into the file manager, but when I drag them into the project timeline they only show the audio track as if there is no video track at all. There is no error message at all.

I would like to be able to resolve this without converting the files.

Comment: If it helps, they were encoded with ffmpeg

Comment: You might want to consult with http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/support/technicalsupport.asp please read their knowledge base first to see if your issue has already been covered.

Comment: @filzilla Searching that site for mp4v yields no results.

Comment: He can still open a trouble ticket with Sony Creative Software.

Comment: Related: [How to make Vegas Pro open AVI files](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20464/how-to-make-vegas-pro-open-avi-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by installing [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). Apparently VLC has some necessary codecs that Vegas Pro uses.

After installing VLC I was able to import the video and use it normally with no hindrances.

---

After some time, this issue cropped up on a different computer. Installing/reinstalling VLC did not work.

I installed [AVI Codec Pack Pro v2.4.0 from Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Codec-Packs-Video-Codecs/D-i-v-X-AV-Codec-Pack-Pro.shtml) and the issue was resolved.

If Softpedia no longer has the file available by the time you are reading this, the file was titled "avi.codec.pack.pro.v2.4.0.setup.exe" and was 16.7MB (17,538,685 bytes). A google search at the time of update yields other sources for download, but some are concerned with malware imbedded in it. I haven't noticed any malware with the softpedia download.

Comment: AVI codec pack still working and available as of this date.

Answer (score 0):

To get the proper codecs supporting FOURCC of MP4V you can install ffdshow codec pack http://www.videohelp.com/software/ffdshow/old-versions some of the older versions are nicer. the one i use the most is rev3631 because its the last one that contained the MPEG1 and MPEG2 encoders/decoders with it.

Comment: That's how I was able to record with the codec in the first place. ffdshow seems to have the encoder for MP4V, but not the decoders, or at least, not any decoder Vegas Pro will use.

Comment: ahh, for the decoders, you might need to run the vfw configration or decoder configurations that come with ffdshow. When you look there, ensure mpeg4 is enabled, or maybe its divx, or mp4, not sure how it might be listed.